# contains giving faulty results

Tags: java, contains, treeset

I have a class 'CoAutoria' that's suposed to hold 2 instances of an 'Author' class (which only has a name, for now) and the number of articles those authors have in common.
In order to figure out the top 10 of co-authors (regarding number of articles) I created a TreeSet of 'CoAutoria', to hold the total of articles, for each pair.
I need to cycle through a Map of years, gather the different authors and their respective Set of co-Authors. Then, for each pair, create an instance of 'CoAutoria' and: add it to the treeset (if it doesn't already exists); or simply sum its number of articles to the one existing on the set.

I already created the compareTo method, to insert it on the treeset, and created the equals method so that the order of the authors doesn't matter.

Here's the main code:`

```
public class CoAutoria implements Comparable<CoAutoria>
{    
private Autor autor1;
private Autor autor2;
private int artigosComum;
(...) 
}


@Override
public int compareTo(CoAutoria a2)
{
    String thisAutor1 = autor1.getNome();
    String thisAutor2 = autor2.getNome();
    String caAutor1 = a2.getAutor1().getNome();
    String caAutor2 = a2.getAutor2().getNome();
    if((autor1.equals(a2.getAutor1()) && autor2.equals(a2.getAutor2())) || (autor1.equals(a2.getAutor2()) && autor2.equals(a2.getAutor1())))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {               

       return 1;
    }        
}    
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if(this == o)
    {
        return true;
    }


    if( o == null || o.getClass() != this.getClass())
        return false;

    CoAutoria ca  = (CoAutoria) o;
    String thisAutor1 = autor1.getNome();
    String thisAutor2 = autor2.getNome();
    String caAutor1 = ca.getAutor1().getNome();
    String caAutor2 = ca.getAutor2().getNome();
    if((thisAutor1.equals(caAutor1) && thisAutor2.equals(caAutor2)) || (thisAutor1.equals(caAutor2) && thisAutor2.equals(caAutor1)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {               
        return false;
    }

}
```

The main problem is: When I check if the set already has a certain instance of 'CoAutoria', (I'm using the contains() method of TreeSet), it gives me faulty results...sometimes it checks correctly that the Pair A-B already exists in that set (on the form of B-A), but sometimes it doesn't... For what I've read, the contains uses the equals method, so that's not suposed to happen..right?

[EDIT:]
Since the first post I started to think that maybe the problem resided on the compareTo..So I changed it to

```
public int compareTo(CoAutoria a2)
{
String thisAutor1 = autor1.getNome();
String thisAutor2 = autor2.getNome();
String caAutor1 = a2.getAutor1().getNome();
String caAutor2 = a2.getAutor2().getNome();
if(this.equals(a2))
{
    System.out.println("return 0");
    return 0;
}
else
{               
   int aux = thisAutor1.compareTo(caAutor1);
   if(aux != 0)
   {
       return aux;

   }
   else
   {
       return thisAutor2.compareTo(caAutor2);

   }

}
```

}

But it still gives my bad results..I thought I'd figured it now: if it's the same 'CoAutoria', I return 0, if not I go through the names, and order it by their compareTo values..but something's missing

Comment: There's not enough to go on in your example, but .... Instead of using contains, loop through and you'll probably find that testing with equals() does not work either.

Comment: @DariusX. The problems is not with his equals, it's with the `compareTo` function.  When the compareTo function doesn't work correctly, neither will the `contains` method for ordered Collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `contains` method is breaking, because your `compareTo` method is always returning 0 or positive,  no negatives. This means your `compareTo` is inconsistent.  A correct implementation should return 0 if the authors are the same, or positive **and** negative values when the authors are different.

Example (assuming `author1` is different than `author2`):

```
 int i = author1.compareTo(author2); // i should be positive or negative
 int j = author2.compareTo(author1); // j should be the opposite of i
```

Yours will return `1` for both of the above cases, which will make ordered Collections not work as no element is ever `smaller`.  As another example imagine if you had a Binary Tree(an ordered collection) that had the elements [1-10].  If you were searching for the element 5, your binary tree when comparing 5 against any element would always say that it was equal or greater.

How exactly you should change it is up to you.  But an idea would be to sort the authors by name, then iterate over both collections and compare the authors together lexicographically.

EDIT: Even after your edit to your methods they are still not consistent.  Try the following, they aren't the most efficient but should work unless you really want to optimize for speed.  Notice they first sort to make sure author1 and author2 are in order before they are compared with the other `CoAutor` which is also sorted. I don't do any null checking and assume both are valid authors.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof CoAutoria)) return false;
    if (o == this) return true;
    return this.compareTo((CoAutoria)o) == 0;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(CoAutoria o) {
    List<String> authors1 = Arrays.asList(autor1.getNome(), autor2.getNome());
    List<String> authors2 = Arrays.asList(o.autor1.getNome(), o.autor2.getNome());
    Collections.sort(authors1);
    Collections.sort(authors2);
    for (int i=0;i<authors1.size();i++){
        int compare = authors1.get(i).compareTo(authors2.get(i));
        if (compare != 0)
            return compare;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I tried to improve my compareTo method (I edited the initial post) but still I'm making some kind of error..

Comment: Check out my revised answer.  Your methods are still wrong, so try what I suggested.

Comment: Yeah, just now I figured that if I don't have my pairs ordered the same way, I can't use the method I created, thanks!
Another solution that, in my case, is doable, is ordering the Authors as I create an instance of 'CoAutoria'. But on a situation that I couldn't do that, your method would be more useful :)